# Is a draw possible in Quarto with the advanced rules?

Tags: quarto

Quarto has a set of basic rules which describes the winner as the one who align 4 pieces sharing a common trait. The alignment can be horizontal, vertical or diagonal.

An advanced rule states that if 4 pieces share a trait and are disposed to form a 2*2 square then it is a winning position.

The board being 4*4, the advanced rule adds 9 winning positions.

Is a draw possible with this advance rule ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A draw is definitely possible. For example here is a game I played against myself on an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nicholas.kroetsch.quarto&hl=en).

[image]

However I've not seen any results about whether this version of the game is a draw with perfect play or not (in contrast to the basic game which is known to be a [draw](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~wouter/Talks/quarto.pdf)). The extra victory condition might mean that perfect play results in a win for one of the two players.